# RequestMappingHandlerAdapter with MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter doesn't work well in Date Format

Tags: json, date, jackson, simpledateformat, spring-4

I use spring4
I config the simpleDateFormat and timezone property of ObjectMapper for jackson2HttpMessageConverter, but it doesn't work well;

the spring.xml:

```
   <context:annotation-config/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

<bean id="timeZone" class="java.util.TimeZone" factory-method="getDefault"></bean>
<!--&lt;!&ndash;Jackson - objectMapper format date setting &ndash;&gt;-->
<bean id="objectMapperFactoryBean"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
      p:indentOutput="true" p:simpleDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" p:timeZone-ref="timeZone">
</bean>
<bean id="jackson2HttpMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
            <value>text/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
            <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapperFactoryBean"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

the RequestBody json:

```
{
"secKillPromotionVo": {
    "type": 20,
    "name": "test4-xxxx",
    "showTime": "2017-06-16T16:25:41.000Z",
    "startTime": "2017-06-18T00:00:41.000Z",
    "endTime": "2017-06-18T23:55:41.000Z",
    "activityId": null,
    "email": "yinyuxia@le.com",
    "platform": "LeWin",
    "shopCode": "1",
    "shopName": "xxxxx",
    "createdUserId": "112424",
    "createdUser": xxxx"
},
"secKillProductList": [
    {
        "productId": "H04011000088",
        "productName": "xxxx",
        "productType": 1,
        "originPrice": 399900,
        "promotionPrice": 299900,
        "promotionStock": 1000,
        "maxNumPerUser": 1
    }
]
}
```

the debug screen:
[image]

and the Response json:

```
{
"status": 1,
"msg": "successful",
"data": {
    "id": 2753,
    "type": 20,
    "name": "test4-XXXXX",
    "showTime": 1497630341000,
    "startTime": 1497744041000,
    "endTime": 1497830141000,
    "status": 0,
    "activityId": null,
    "createdUserId": "1234",
    "createdUser": "XXX",
    "email": "XXXXX",
    "platform": "XXXX",
    "shopCode": "1",
    "shopName": "XXXX"
}
}
```

The ObjectMapper doesn't work well,the out Date field is serialized with default settings.

Now I just add @JsonFormat annotation for all Date fields to fix this issue, but anyone can help me to resolve it?

the POJO with @JsonFormat annotation:

```
public class SecKillPromotionVO {
private Integer id;
@ValidPromotionType(value = {PromotionType.secKill})
private Byte type;
@NotBlank
private String name;
@NotNull
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",timezone = "GMT+8")
private Date showTime;
@NotNull
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",timezone = "GMT+8")
private Date startTime;
@NotNull
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",timezone = "GMT+8")
private Date endTime;
private Byte status;
private String activityId;
private String createdUserId;
private String createdUser;
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: That’s a long question. Any particular reason in 2017 you are still using the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`? I have little experience with Jackson, my limited understanding is that you should prefer to use [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) so you can use the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: @OleV.V.  the lib you suggested work in Java 8, but my production environment is Java 7

Comment: … and while the date and time API itself has been backported to Java 7, I take it that the Jackson integration hasn’t. I wish you could upgrade to Java 8.